# Using Panels to display Taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels

My Drupal 6 taxonomy terms are linked to two types of content, one is called Results (text) the other is a Photo.  Is it possible through Panels to develop a node where a user can select a term via a drop down menu then it will display only the Results and the pictures related to that term?  My goal is to have all of the results together in their own region and the same with the photo.

If it can be done, is there a recommended recipe I should follow?

If it can't be done any suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Panels can do this using the Views module. The two modules work very well together to arrange your content on a page, but Views is the workhorse for sorting through the content and selecting what you want.  Check out the video series "Taming the Beast" at Nodeone.se for how to use Views.  They also have a series on Panels/Page Manger that shows how to link them.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think panels is required here at all. Create one view that returns content of type Results and Photo. Have the content type as a field that will be hidden from display and then group your results by the content type.